# Android Auto Desktop Head Unit (DHU) shows black screen on launch

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-auto

I’m trying to connect to the Desktop Head Unit (DHU) for Android Auto testing and keep getting a black screen when I launch it. I can see the red & green touch artefacts when I click & right-click on it.

[image: DHU with black screen and red & green touch artefacts]

I have followed all the instructions here: https://developer.android.com/training/cars/testing.

I get no console errors and I have ensured the Android Auto app has developer mode enabled & the head unit server is running. I have also tried different tcp ports.

I am using a Mac with stock Android 10 on a Pixel 3 for the phone part of the connection, latest updates to everything. I have also tried another physical device with Marshmallow 6.0.1. Android Auto app on the phone is version 5.5.602944-release.

This is the first time I am using the DHU and I have tried clearing the cache & resetting everything on the Android Auto App on the phone.

I did notice when I have the Android Auto app open and I launch the DHU from the terminal the Android Auto app on the phone closes (which I don't think should happen - but I may be wrong there).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I also had this issue, everything seemed to be working fine, but the DHU remained black every time.
I've been using a pixel 4 with android 10, and mac os.

1. Start by resetting the android auto app
2. revoke all permissions
3. close the DHU
4. when following the instructions, never tap the android auto app icon.
5. go through the settings -> applications -> android auto -> extend advance -> additions settings in the app -> and here enable dev settings.
6. start the server
7. start the dhu
8. if the black screen is visible, then stop the server, exit DHU
9. start the server again, and open DHU.

--- at this point the application should launch showing you the initial screen and asking also permissions for the different things.

10. allow all and continue the usual initial setup.
    The DHU now should show the AA home.

These steps worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Problem for me was the initial permission on the phone in Android Auto as I tried DHU the first time.

On the mobile phone in Android Auto I started the development server.

As I started ./desktop-head-unit on my Mac the effect was that on the mobile device Android Auto wiped away.

Using on the phone the Android Task Manager (the square button) I was able to switch back to Android Auto. After that I was able to give the needed permission. Result was that DHU on the Mac was terminated. But after restart it showed my the expected screen.